# Different array order on specs in different machines running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, odbc

I'm in the process of making a Rails application be able to run on different machines other than the VM which is shared around (CentOS 5.5).

I've got the tests to pass on my OSX running 10.7.3, except for a few, which do output ok results, but with a different order, such as:

```
'some test' FAILED
expected: [831557419, 372199733, 89450236],
     got: [372199733, 831557419, 89450236] (using ==)
```

I'm kinda lost here on how to debug and solve this. Any tips or leads that I could take a look?

I'm using unixodbc, freetds and activerecord-sqlserver-adapter. It is a Rails 2.3.8 application, and RSpec 1.3.

PS: Editing to point out that there are fixtures in the project. Someone suggested this could be the problem (fixtures are being created on a different order here), but I'm lost on how to solve it.

PPS: This is a current application being run on several VMs cloned from an original VM.

The tests have most of these expected values *hardcoded*, but the tests do pass on those VMs. I would rather not change the actual tests if possible.

I am new to the codebase, on a consulting job. I'm trying to make this work on my machine to prove we can use any machine to develop (instead of a provided VM no one likes to code). The order is important.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing some of the app/spec code. Are you relying on results being  returned in a specific order than you're not actually specifying?

Comment: Yeah, for example, Postgres doesn't actually guarantee the order of results, so if you aren't specifying a return order, it will be random.

Comment: You've not made it clear if the order is important, ie changes the meaning.  If not, just apply a `.sort` to your comparison.

Comment: I've updated the question according to your arguments. As I said, I'm new to the codebase. On some tests, yes, order is important. The said specs aren't pretty, but one of my first tasks is to make this platform-independent, without changing too much code if possible. While I could change some, I cannot change all of them. I'm using an example that shows the behavior expected, and the actual behavior on my machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by changing the Ruby version. Apparently 1.8.7 @ patchlevel > 250 changes something that causes this behavior.

Comment: indeed, before that ruby didn't respect the order of arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If the output is acceptable in any order, use this form:

```
output.should =~ [831557419, 372199733, 89450236]
```

Comment: I would like to not change the specs. These are working on other machines.

Comment: Semantically, unless the order is something you are intending to test, changing tests is probably a smarter move.